# Send Email with Attachement using SSRS Action Property

Tags: email, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

For the customized reason, I developed a report that is reporting on the SharePoint document lists and so far it's all good.

By using Action property, I linked the original SharePoint path to SSRS and user can open the document using the link from the report very easily.

**New Requirements**

Business wants *a link* in the report to send the email. So that when the user clicks on that *new link*, the document should be emailed directly to the specified email address.

Is there a way to do such thing using **action property** in SSRS?

I'm using SSRS 2008R2

---

**Note:**
*I want to explore my options is SSRS before going out of this domain.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the recipient of the email have access to the sharepoint document? You could just use the mailto link and create the URL to the document within the body of the email.

Comment: Yes. they are all internal accounts and have access on Intranet.

Comment: Is it acceptable then that they just get an email with a link already embedded to that document? I believe that's the best you can do with SSRS alone and you'd have to build another process outside of SSRS if you wanted to get your exact scenario working.

Comment: Actually not a bad idea... need to talk to business for that. thanks for clue Daniel. Appreciated.

Comment: No problem.  If you need to stay within SSRS for the user's sake but are willing to create a separate process, then you could build a simple web app that takes the report path and email via parameter and does the email in the background for the user. The user would just click the link, see javascript open a new browser window, and get a status message saying that the email is sent.

Comment: I would say use a mailto: link as the URL action to take, and in the body of the link have the url pointing to the target report.  This will open a local email message in their default email app.  They'd still need to click SEND

Answer (score 1):

No, what you are asking about, or attempting to make happen with a Action property is not possible. Their best bet would be to run the report, export the report the Excel, or Word, and then email the report from within that application.

Action properties only allow for a few things to happen:

- Go to another report
- Go to a bookmark within the current report
- Go to a URL

The go to a URL can be a `mailto:` protocol, but all that would do is open the end users default email client; there would be no attachment, or report results in the email body.

Comment: Thanks, Richards. I'm not after emailing the report itself but the target document that the report link is opening from SharePoint library but your point is taken. I'll wait for other answers too. Regards.